# Why is an RDBMS bad to store a considerably big graph?

Tags: graph, rdbms, graph-databases

I started using a graph database to store a big graph that im generating. But im not convinced as to why to use a graph database to do my job, and why not do what i want with a conventional RDBMS. My question in specific is, why is a Relational Database bad or rather Graph Database is BETTER than RDBMS to store graphs?

Comment: How are you going to query your graph? Are you finding paths? Generating recommendations? Computing network statistics? How big is "considerably big" in terms of the number of of nodes and edges?

Comment: Please notice that "relational database" means only that its users see the database as a collection tables and have relational operators for extracting information. The physical implementation of storage and querying engine is a completely orthogonal decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading Graph Databases (early release, available here: http://graphdatabases.com/) it all comes down to performance. Depending on how deep or recursive your query is, the longer it will take for your RDBMS or graph database to return results. Traditional RDBMS are not designed for the quick traversal of relationships between entities whereas graph databases are built specifically for this. This may not be an issue if your recursion is only 2 levels deep but after this level performance apparently degrades significantly.

Please take this with a grain of salt. This is coming directly from Graph Databases and I have not replicated these results.